# Can puppeteer be used to automate clicking on submenu?

Tags: puppeteer, ui-automation, browser-automation

I am trying to automate clicking on a submenu using puppeteer but this doesn't work

```
var frames = await serv.page.frames();
let lastFrame = frames[frames.length-1];
await lastFrame.waitForNavigation();

await lastFrame.waitForSelector('.reportBuilder-view');
const [more] = await lastFrame.$x("//button[contains(., 'More Actions')]");
await more.click();

console.log(await lastFrame.content());
await serv.wait(1000);
console.log(await lastFrame.content());
console.log('wait for subscribe?')

await lastFrame.waitForSelector('a[title="Subscribe"]');
await lastFrame.click('a[title="Subscribe"]');
```

I am able to simulate the click on the "More Actions" button by line `await more.click();`

However, I am not able to initiate a click on a submenu item.

The script fails at line `await lastFrame.waitForSelector('a[title="Subscribe"]');` and can't select the proper anchor element.

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: waiting for selector `a[title="Su
bscribe"]` failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded
```

I am new to `puppeteer` and I can't understand why this code doesn't work.

Maybe the problem is that the submenu is embedded in an element with absolute positioning?

```
outline: 0px; position: absolute; right: inherit; top: 52px; left: 615px;
```

Maybe it is added to DOM dynamically but why can't it find it since for 30 seconds it is already displayed and added to the DOM?

When I look through output from `lastFrame.content()` I can see that the element is present in the DOM

```
<li class="slds-dropdown__item actionBarButto
nGroup-action-item report-action-ReportScheduleAction" id="liVM0LRxvZ-item-3" role="presentati
on"><a aria-disabled="false" href="javascript:void(0);" data-index="3" role="menuitem" tabinde
x="-1"><span class="slds-truncate" title="Subscribe">Subscribe</span></a></li>
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

I also tried waiting for the XPath but this didn't work either

```
await lastFrame.waitForXPath("//li[@class='report-action-ReportScheduleAction']/a");


const [li] = await lastFrame.$x("//li[@class='report-action-ReportScheduleAction']");
console.log('try to click the li');
await li.click();
```

Comment: Is that menu being animated?

Comment: not sure. Actually, I should probably click on the span instead of anchor...

Answer (score 0):

Actually the title is property of the span instead of anchor.

```
<li class="slds-dropdown__item actionBarButto
    nGroup-action-item report-action-ReportScheduleAction" id="liVM0LRxvZ-item-3" role="presentati
    on">
    <a aria-disabled="false" href="javascript:void(0);" data-index="3" role="menuitem" tabinde
    x="-1">
        <span class="slds-truncate" title="Subscribe">Subscribe</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

When I click on the span, it works

```
await lastFrame.waitForSelector('span[title="Subscribe"]');
await lastFrame.click('span[title="Subscribe"]');
```

Still didn't figure out why `li` selector doesn't work